# How we can use $toUpper with array fields?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How we can use toUpper with array field, I have the following query which compare array field 'locations' with an array of camel case items, now my problem is how we can convert `locations` field values to upper case and then compare with array.

```
var array = ["KABUL","KAPISA","WARDAK","LOGAR","PARWAN","BAGHLAN","NANGARHAR","LAGHMAN",
                                "BAMYAN","PANJSHER","KHOST","GHAZNI","KUNARHA","PAKTYA","PAKTIKA","KUNDUZ",
                                "NOORISTAN","SAMANGAN","TAKHAR","DAYKUNDI","BADAKHSHAN","BALKH","GHOR",
                                "UROZGAN","FARYAB","ZABUL","SAR-E-PUL","NIMROZ","JAWZJAN","HELMAND","BADGHIS",
                                "KANDAHAR","FARAH","HERAT"];

db.getCollection('test').aggregate([

{ "$project": {
    "locations": {
      "$map": {
        "input": {
          "$setIntersection": ["$locations", array ]
        },
        "in": { "k": "$$this", "v": 1 }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$locations" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$locations.k",
    "v": { "$sum": "$locations.v" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
     "_id": null,
     "obj": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$v" } } 
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$obj" }  
  }}
])
```

`locations` field is like :

```
"locations" : [ 
    "Afghanistan", 
    "Kabul",
    .....
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to transform "each" element of course:

```
  { "$project": {
    "locations": {
      "$map": {
        "input": {
          "$setIntersection": [
            { "$map": { "input": "$locations", "in": { "$toUpper": "$$this" } } },
            array
          ]
        },
        "in": { "k": "$$this", "v": 1 }
      }
    }
  }},
```